# Tuning Airflow's Celery visibility timeout

Tags: redis, celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

***Edit (2020-4-18):*** Added context about metadata database.  Added context about StatsD.

### Background

I operate an **Airflow 1.10.3** deployment.  It uses MySQL 5.7 as the metadata database.  It uses the **`CeleryExecutor`** with **Redis 3.2.5** as the Celery broker.

I build the Airflow package, my DAG code, and any other relevant configs into **1 Docker image**.

My deployment starts Docker containers for each of the Webserver, Flower server, Scheduler, and Workers; they are all spawned from that 1 Docker image.  Redis is also running in a Docker container; but not from the same Docker image as the other Airflow components.  MySQL is not containerized and is kept up and running as any traditional OLTP database would be.  A deploy sequence consists of:

1. Building a new Docker image with any changed DAG code, etc.
2. Killing the currently running Airflow Docker containers (i.e. Webserver, Scheduler, etc.); except for the Redis container.
3. Spinning up new Docker containers from the newly built Docker image.

**The only Airflow component that doesn't get "wiped and out replaced" during a deploy is the Redis container.**

I (continuously) deploy anywhere from 3-7 times a day.

### Issue

Often, during normal operation, a set of Airflow tasks end up showing the following in their logs:

```
[2018-02-23 12:57:01,711] {models.py:1190} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: userdbs.dump.dedicated 2018-02-21 02:00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
[2018-02-23 12:57:01,711] {models.py:1190} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: userdbs.dump.clustered 2018-02-21 02:00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance Not Already Running' FAILED: Task is already running, it started on 2018-02-23 06:54:44.431988.
```

These tasks are usually very long-running.  And when I investigate, the underlying task is usually legitamitely still running.  I have DAGs that have tasks that process large amounts of data and legitimately need to run anywhere from 6-10 hours to complete successfully.  So, discussion on breaking down these tasks to process less data should be out of scope for this question.

**I believe there is a correlation to how I do deploys and when the above logs usually show up.**  But I don't have hard data to back that up.

Some online searching shows that increasing the Celery visibility timeout to a value higher than my expected longest running task (across all DAGs) should resolve this issue.  **I plan on implementing this.**

But my primary concern is whether the **increased visibility timeout (likely to ~11 hours) + not killing the Redis container on deploys** will leave me with Celery taking ~11 hours to notice that it needs to reschedule a task.  This concern stems from this comment here from the Celery docs (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html#id1):

```
Note that Celery will redeliver messages at worker shutdown, so having a long visibility timeout will only delay the redelivery of ‘lost’ tasks in the event of a power failure or forcefully terminated workers.
```

### Questions

1. **Is my concern** about Celery taking ~11 hours to notice that it needs to reschedule a task **valid** (given my deployment setup)?
2. Should I consider **killing the Redis container** along with all other Airflow components?  My primary concern here is whether the Scheduler is smart enough to rebuild an accurate view of the world once it starts up.
3. Are the "Dependencies not met" messages related to something **other than Celery visibility timeouts**?  If so, what?  And do new Airflow versions address this?
4. I have StatsD metrics configured.  Are there specific metrics that I could be analyzing to get a sense of what's happening here?  (Or new metrics introduced in newer Airflow versions that can help with observability here?)

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer all your questions but:

- which DB are you using for Airflow? Postgres? Are you keeping it up?

I don't think you should touch your Redis container (in other words - keep it up).
I think that you should configure it as your Celery's backend result as well.
In addition, consider the following configurations (I'm using it):

- [CELERY_ACKS_LATE](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-acks-late) - tasks will be acknowledged after the task has been executed. Also read this [faq](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/faq.html#should-i-use-retry-or-acks-late):

  > The acks_late setting would be used when you need the task to be
  >   executed again if the worker (for some reason) crashes mid-execution.
- [CELERY_TRACK_STARTED](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/configuration.html#celery-track-started) - Having a “started” state can be useful for when there are long running tasks and there is a need to report which task is currently running.

Regard the metrics, for Celery you can use Flower (don't restart this container!) and I saw that there's an option to configure `Statsd` for Airflow (I didn't try it). Check out the following configurations in `airflow.cfg`:

```
# Statsd (https://github.com/etsy/statsd) integration settings
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow
```

Comment: (1) Those 2 Celery configurations look promising!!! I will report back. (2) MySQL is my result backend. Airflow 1.10.10 docs recommend a database (airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.10/…). What's the benefit of Redis over MySQL? (3) What are the downsides restarting Flower? Is basic functionality being impaired? Or is it just that metrics Flower records will be "restarted".

Comment: (2) It's not Redis vs. MySQL. Redis is used for managing Celery and MySQL for managing Airflow. I just want to make sure that you don't restart MySQL because you didn't mention it. (3) Flower save its data in memory. It doesn't rely on Celery's backend (Redis in your case) so restarting it makes you blind and you wont be able to understand what happened in you scenario. In your deployments you don't want to restart it - it better to do it periodically (corn? once a week? depend on your system load). Don't forget to update here / upvote / accept if it helped ;)

Comment: (2) Right.  I'm not referring to the use of MySQL as my metadata database (`sql_alchemy_conn`); I'm referring to using MySQL as my result backend (`result_backend`).  I use MySQL as my result backend since the Airflow docs recommend a database.  But it looks like you're using Redis as your result backend.  I want to learn more about your design to go with Redis over a database.

(3) Makes sense.

(4) Yes, once I try the recommendations in your answer + they work, I will tag the answer appropriately.